# Restoring SQL Server database from .ss file

Tags: sql-server, database

The snapshot I created in server is deleted, but I do have a copy of the `.ss` file. Is there a way to restore the database from the `.ss` file?

Comment: Ah, I hate to break it to you, but what is a .ss file? SQL Server backup files generally are named ".bak" - thoug hthat is more a convention. But without us knowing what file you have, all we can do is point you do the documentation on how to restore a database baclup. So, what IS that .ss file? One file does NOT sound like a db backup.

Comment: Or moment, you mean snapshot? BAD NEWS - snapshots to my knowledge are not a full database. This is like "I have a list of changes on a document I deleted, can I reconstruct the whole text from the list of things I am supposed to change" - no.

Comment: yup, you are correct. .ss is a snapshot file.

Comment: in that case, can we reattach the snapshot from the file?

Comment: Again, you do not have a database. YOu have a list of CHANGES. SO no, you can not - you miss the text. If I tell you "change sentence 3, word 4 on line 3 on page 12 is spelled wrong and the 12th chapter should be rewritten" - can you reconstruct the manuscript from that? you do have a LITTLE, but no, you can not restore the db. You do not have the db.

Comment: Didn't you have a maintenance plan to do backups? If you have snapshots, were you using those for replication? Why would you take snapshots if you weren't using them to push to another copy of your db?

Comment: @TomTom, sorry i should have been bit clear in my question(i will edit it).
I have the original database from which i initially created the snapshot, for some reason my snapshot went into "suspect/read only" mode.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible.

When a database snapshot is created, the ".ss" file is basically empty.  As data pages are modified in the database for the first time after snapshot creation, the original page is copied to the .ss file.

Restoring database from a snapshot will just copy back the original data pages into the database.

If there is any issue with the snapshot, SQL Server prioritizes transactions execution over snapshot integrity.  So, the snapshot becomes suspect and, from that point, it's impossible to restore database to snapshot state.

How a snapshot can become suspect? many reasons:

- SQL Server can't write to the file
- disk is full
- snapshot file is too fragmented and reached some NTFS limits (see [This Microsoft KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/1450-and-665-errors-running-dbcc-checkdb). While the article is about DBCC CHECKDB, it can also affect any snapshot)